# Itextsharp special characters like <

Tags: itext, special-characters

I am generating pdf using itextsharp i have one requirement to display << and >> in the pdf page how can i do this

Answer (score 2):

If you know the entity number of the special character you can create that special character simply by using the following code.

```
document.Add(Phrase.GetInstance(" This is " + (char)945));
```

Substitute your entity number instead of 945. Hope this helps.

Edit: FontSelector class in iTextSharp will help you further if you have the required font with the symbols.